# akka-quartz-scheduler: No matching quartz configuration found for schedule

Tags: akka, scheduler

I'm trying to run a sample of akka-quartz-scheduler, I got the akka-quickstart-java, and created a new main class for the scheduler sample, then I added the application.conf (under main/resources) and I added the dependencies to build.sbt.

I tried to load manually the Config with: ConfigFactory.load(), I got the content of the config file correctly, but it appears that the file is never seen by the schedulerExtension.

SchedulerQuickstart.java

```
public class SchedulerQuickstart {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("helloscheduler");
        try {
            QuartzSchedulerExtension schedulerExtension = new QuartzSchedulerExtension((ExtendedActorSystem) system);
            Date firstExecutionDate=schedulerExtension.schedule("GreetingSchedule",
                    system.actorOf(Printer.props(), "printerActor"),
                    new Printer.Greeting("This is an scheduled message"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
        }
        finally {
            system.terminate();
        }
   }
}
```

application.conf

```
akka.quartz.schedules {
  GreetingSchedule {
    description = "Task that fires off every 30 seconds"
    expression = "*/30 * * ? * *"
    maxRetries = 2
  }
}
```

in build.sbt:

```
"com.enragedginger" %% "akka-quartz-scheduler" % "1.8.0-akka-2.5.x"
```

When I run the code, I got: 
No matching quartz configuration found for schedule 'GreetingSchedule'